# How can I preemptively postpone svn merge conflicts?

Tags: svn, merge

I often encounter conflicts when doing a Subversion merge, for example:

```
svn merge -r10347:HEAD ^/branches/header-and-navbar
```

I know about `--dry-run`, and I do that to get a preview.

But then after running it for real, if I want to choose "postpone" for each conflict, that can take a long time for a lot of files.

How can I tell Subversion ahead of time not to ask me for each file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`svn merge -h` lists all the options, and the one you're looking for is

```
svn merge --accept postpone
```

or

```
svn merge --accept p
```

Comment: It somehow wasn't accepting "p" as a valid value. Worked with "postpone"